Sums and Products of Adjacent Numbers 2
Inspired by this question
Given a sequence of N integers, we can generate a sequence of length 3N-2 by appending the sums and products of adjacent pairs of integers in the original sequence.
Can you provide a sequence of 7 non-negative integers which generates a sequence, in this way, of 19 distinct integers which are all less than 34?

For longer sequences: N=8 has solutions with integers less than 40, N=9 less than 50, and N=10 less than 60.

@DanielMathias Indeed, the minimax values are 39, 48, and 54.


 6,4,5,3,11,2,16


 A little bit of guess and check but main solve process was shooting for 33,32 on the products and the 6,4,5,3 pattern for the 8,9,10 sums (all unique products too). Last step was fixing the ends to not be any value already used and lowest I found was 16 (to add to 18 and multiply to 32).


Good answer, well done!

I wrote a short brute-force program:

 It checked that up to the symmetry there are two solutions:


 $$6\,4\, 5 \,3\, 11\, 2\, 16$$


 $$8\, 4\, 6\, 3\, 11\, 2\, 15.$$


Thank you for your answer. I gave the tick to the other answer as it had some explanation about how to find a solution path on paper but well done on the code.

@hexomino It is OK. I started to think about the puzzle, but soon realized that there are too few possibilities to check and I can quickly wrote a program.

@bobble Done. The program is in good old Pascal. I am sorry for seven nested cycles (I did not expect to expose the program).
